# SPARQL HTML result displaying in next line

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, virtuoso, rdfs

I'm executing SPARQL query on virtuoso SPARQL editor.

The result of query in HTML format is displaying in next line for each corresponding record as shown on below image:

Kindly advise how to resolve this display issue.

Here is the SPARQL query:

```
prefix DOL:   <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/v1#>
prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select ?cName ?domain ?dValues ?method ?rType{
{
  ?class foaf:name "MyJavaClass" .
}
{ ?class foaf:name ?cName }
union
{ ?class DOL:belongsTo ?domain }
union
{ ?class2 DOL:domainName ?dValues }
union 
{ ?class DOL:hasMethod ?method }
union 
{ ?class2 DOL:returnType ?rType }

}
```

[SPARQL output on virtuoso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMRGr.png)

Comment: Could you please use the stack overflow image hosting for images, rather than using other sites where images night not stick around.

Comment: Asked on the mailing list and got an answer there as well...

Comment: [Thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/message/35174598/) on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/)...

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Point taken. Updated with stack overflow image hosting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` is for [matching alternatives](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#alternatives), so that the results of your query would match any of the patterns joined by `UNION`. If you want the results to match all the triple patterns in your query, you just [group them](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#GroupPatterns):

```
PREFIX DOL:   <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/v1#>
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?cName ?domain ?dValues ?method ?rType
WHERE {
  ?class foaf:name "MyJavaClass" ;
    DOL:belongsTo ?domain ;
    DOL:hasMethod ?method .
  ?class2 DOL:domainName ?dValues ;
    DOL:returnType ?rType .
}
```

If you want the results to match only some of the triple patterns, you can use [`OPTIONAL`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#optionals) to wrap the patterns that the results don't need to match, such as in the following:

```
PREFIX DOL:   <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/v1#>
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?cName ?domain ?dValues ?method ?rType
WHERE {
  ?class foaf:name "MyJavaClass" ;
    DOL:belongsTo ?domain .
  OPTIONAL {
    ?class DOL:hasMethod ?method .
  }
  ?class2 DOL:domainName ?dValues ;
    DOL:returnType ?rType .
}
```

Comment: The whole query is wrong because he/she didn't understand SPARQL and RDF. For instance `?class2` is totally useless and `domainName` of course refers to the `?domain`. And `returnType` refers to the `?method`. I answered it already on the mailing list, there I also could see the data. Indeed, without it's impossible to show the correct query.

Comment: @jindrichm: Thank you for detailed explanation. The next line problem is resolved by using grouping.